# Why Jquery renders as HTMLString when I don't want it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, i'm trying to paste an image URL, and I got to know that the problem is that backend is returning an image url properly, but razor for some reasson renders it as HtmlString (my problem here is that the image has "&" on the path, and razor replaces it for `"&amp;"`)

**Take this as an example** *(is not retrieving a picture url, is just to get the idea of the problem):*

```
@functions
{
    private String GetPictureSrc()
    {
       return "&&&&";
    }
}
```

Then in the javascript section:

```
        $("#anImage").attr("src", "@GetPictureSrc()");
```

When I see the generated code, I see this:

```
<img id="anImage" src="&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;">
```

I would like to see exactly what is returned by the function!

```
<img id="anImage" src="&&&&">
```

**EDIT:**
In addition, I just found that the problem is in Jquery, not razor, If I try like this, it works fine, but unfortunatelly is not what I need...

```
<img id="anImage" src="@GetPictureSrc()">
```

How can I tell to jquery not to HtmlFy the string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `&amp;` instead of `&` because razor is HTML encoding the result of your c# expression (the call to your `GetPictureSrc` method, which returns a string).

Use `Html.Raw` method if you do not want the encoding to happen.

```
$("#anImage").attr("src", "@Html.Raw(GetPictureSrc())");
```

That will give you the value which is not HTML encoded.

Comment: Indeed, this did the trick. To bad I need to wrap all possible calls with this, I would prefeer to have a StringToHtml() instead a RAW()... but anyway... thanks.